# After running merge in mercurial how do I list files that required a merge?

Tags: mercurial, merge

TortoiseHg adds a "ms" (merge status?) column after doing a merge which indicates 'R' or 'U'.  What is the equivalent command line command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[hg resolve --list](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/a-tour-of-mercurial-merging-work.html)

Found while trying to understand what the 'R' and 'U' stood for in the questions statement ;-)